# How to refer to a certain stdout line in Python?

Tags: python, ffmpeg, ytdl

I'm trying to write a program that downloads a portion of a video using yt-dlp to get the stream link and ffmpeg to download the video. Here's what the program will do:

- Ask the user for the video link, then pass the link to `original_link` variable
- Ask the user for start time and end time, then pass those to `start_time` and `end_time` respectively.
- Using `subprocess`, call the shell command `yt-dlp --get-url <original_link>`.
- yt-dlp will output links line-by-line. If the stream is from Twitch, it is HLS and yt-dlp will return one link only (and the link will be used for both video and audio input). If the stream is from services such as Youtube, yt-dlp will return two links: one audio stream and one video stream (pass audio and video stream link to value `video_stream` and `audio_stream`).
- Then, we will call another `subprocess` command to download the file:

  - If yt-dlp only gives 1 link, then execute: (as I mentioned earlier, this is how a single HLS stream link are used for both video and audio input)

```sh
ffmpeg -ss <start_time> -to <end_time> -i <hls-stream-link> -ss <start_time> -to <end_time> -i <hls-stream-link> output.mkv
```

```
* If yt-dlp gives 2 links (Youtube or video-on-demand), then call:
```

```sh
ffmpeg -ss <start_time> -to <end_time> -i <video_stream> -ss <start_time> -to <end_time> -i <audio_stream> output.mkv
```

I've written an example program like this:

```
import subprocess

# Input video link
original_link = input("Enter the link of the video: ")

# Input start and end time
start_time = input("Enter video start time: ")
end_time = input("Enter video end time: ")

# Get raw url
stream_link = subprocess.Popen(["yt-dlp", "--get-url", original_link], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

while True:
    line = stream_link.stdout.readline()
    if not line:
        break
    


# subprocess.Popen(["ffmpeg", "-ss", start_time, "-to", end_time, "-i"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

But I still have no idea how to refer to certain lines in subprocess stdout. For example, if yt-dlp outputs two links, then I'd like to have them passed on separate values (one for video and one for audio). Here are some sample links for you to use:

1. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YS4e4q9oBaU
2. https://www.twitch.tv/videos/640057509

Thank you for any help!

Comment: You read stdout one line at a time in a while loop; you could also just read all of them (with readlines() or read()) and access the resulting data structure? With `.readlines()` that would just be a list of lines.

Comment: I really don't know how to do that unless you show me some code. I've tried to used both   `.read()` and `.readlines()` but it always return `'int' object has no attribute 'read'` or `readlines`.

Answer (score 0):

A very simplistic example reading the output of ffplay with `subprocess`.

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT

comm_line = ['ffplay','-hide_banner','-autoexit','-i','My.mp4']

try:
    play = Popen(comm_line, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT, universal_newlines=True)
except Exception as e:
    print("ffplay", str(e))

play_pid = play.pid

with play.stdout:
    for i in iter(play.stdout.readline, b''):
        if i != '':
            pass
        else:
            break
        print(i)
```